# chef-solo + postgres result in invalid pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm trying to setup postgres with vagrant + chef solo.

I'm using the official receipt: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/postgresql

As my `Berksfile` contains:

```
site :opscode

cookbook "postgresql"
```

And my `Vagrantfile` chunk is:

```
config.berkshelf.enabled = true

config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|

chef.add_recipe "postgresql::server"

  chef.json = {

  "postgresql" => {
      "version" => "9.2",
      "password" => { "postgres" => "123" },
      config: { 
      "ssl" => "false" 
  },
      pg_hba: [  
          { type: 'local', db: 'all', user: 'all', addr: '', method: 'trust' },
          { type: 'local', db: 'all', user: 'all', addr: '127.0.0.1/32', method: 'trust' },
          { type: 'local', db: 'all', user: 'all', addr: '::1/128 ', method: 'trust' } 
  ]
  }
end
```

The generated contents of: `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

```
# This file was automatically generated and dropped off by Chef!

# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

###########
# Other authentication configurations taken from chef node defaults:
###########

local   all             all                                     trust

local   all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

local   all             all             ::1/128                 trust

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

However if I run `sudo service postgresql restart`, it fails with error:

```
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-11-10 08:12:05 GMT LOG:  invalid authentication method "127.0.0.1/32"
2013-11-10 08:12:05 GMT CONTEXT:  line 17 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf"
2013-11-10 08:12:05 GMT LOG:  invalid authentication method "::1/128"
2013-11-10 08:12:05 GMT CONTEXT:  line 19 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf"
2013-11-10 08:12:05 GMT FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

The problematic entries are those holding the address. Any idea what is wrong in my use case?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think you can leave the address empty as you did in the first line. Try removing that line.

Comment: The first line is OK, actually it's the only line that's OK. The ones that mention an address, should be "host", not "local". And the last one currently is useless.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev thanks for hit, that did it. feel free to add it as answer, I'll be glad to mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line is OK, actually it's the only line that's OK. The ones that mention an address, should be "host", not "local". And the last one currently is useless.

More info in the Postgres' docs - ["Client Authentication", "The pg_hba.conf File"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).